# How to "restart" AnglePath3D[]?

Tags: geometry, geometric-transform

Suppose we start a random path in 3D, stopping at the $5^{th}$ step. Importantly, we make a new random orientation at every new step.

```
(*How many initial steps*)    
initialNsteps=5;

newAngle[] := RandomReal[{-20 °, 20 °}, {1, 3}][[1]]; (*This generates a new random orientation*)

myDummyPath = AnglePath3D[Table[newAngle[], initialNsteps]];
```

Question is, how do we restart `myDummyPath` so it keeps going further nth steps, respecting the last step orientation?

Say, we run the original path storing the following data:

```
myDummyPath =
AnglePath3D[origin, 
 RandomReal[{-20 °, 20 °}, {1, 3}], {"Position", 
  "RotationTranslation", "FrameMatrix", "FrameAngles"}];
```

Interested in explanations about what's the difference between storing "local" vs. "global" frames and which info would be useful to restart the path. From the doc:

[image]

Apparently we can save any of this data:

[image]

We should be able to restart the path after any initial steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want the second-to-last form of calling [`AnglePath3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath3D.html), AnglePath3D[{{$x_0$,$y_0$,$z_0$},$rot_0$},$steps$], which specifies that $rot_0$ is the x-axis direction, i.e. the "global" frame of reference as you call it.

As such, you can save both the "Position" and "FrameMatrix" to restart at will.

Here's a demonstration where I deliberately start form the second-to-last position with the same last direction to show equivalence (you probably want to simply use the last point for your use-case):

```
dummyAngles = Table[newAngle[], initialNsteps];
moreDummyAngles = 
  Prepend[Table[newAngle[], initialNsteps - 1], Last[dummyAngles]];

initialPath = AnglePath3D[dummyAngles, {"Position", "FrameMatrix"}];
nextPath = 
  AnglePath3D[initialPath[[-2]], 
   moreDummyAngles, {"Position", "FrameMatrix"}];

{Opacity[0.25], Red, Sphere[initialPath[[All, 1]], 0.5], Blue, 
  Sphere[nextPath[[All, 1]], 0.5]} // Graphics3D
```

[image]